# django admin url raises error 500 on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am having persistent '500' errors in a django app deployed on heroku. I haven't checked my django admin in a few months since november 2020 but now the error appears when trying to login to admin via the url both in my staging and production versions of the app :

```
django.contrib.sites.models.Site.DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.
```

I am clueless on what might have caused this error since it also affects the production one and no changes have been applied to it since its last working version.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating manually a site object within the console. Did not get an explanation on why it happens now though. After logging in the python shell of the django application:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site.objects.create(pk=1, domain='www.example.com', name='example.com')
```

It is pretty straighforwardly explained there as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gr8CVnRUoDo